# How to extend Mongooose prototype with better saveAsync

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I am using mongoose with bluebird initializing with `promisifyAll`. It's cool and I'm loving promises. But mongoose's `model.save()` returns a function signature like `(err, user, numAffected)` so bluebird's `model.saveAsync()` returns a two-element array rather than the obvious result alone. This makes chaining inconvenient so I've taken to making little helper functions like this:

```
function saveUser(user) {
    return user.saveAsync()
        .spread(function (user, numAffected) {
            return user;
        });
}
```

It would be much easier to add this at the time of promisification to the mongoose prototype and only have to do it once in the entire application... but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 3.0 but right now you could use filters and custom promisifier:

```
// Promisifies only methods named "save"
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"), {
    filter: function(name) {
        return name === "save"
    },
    promisifier: function(save, defaultPromisifier) {
        var saveAsync = defaultPromisifier(save);
        return function() {
            return saveAsync.apply(this, arguments).spread(function(first) {
                return first;
            });
        }
    }
});
// Promisify rest of the mongoose... it will ignore save as it was already promisified
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"));
```

Comment: This is perfect! Cheers @Esailija

Answer (score 0):

You could patch `user.saveAsync`

```
var user_saveAsync = user.saveAsync;
user.saveAsync = function() {
    return user_saveAsync.bind(this)() //-> same as calling `user.saveAsync()`
        .spread(function(user) {      // but now you're returning spreaded result 
            return user;
        });
}
```

Then you can just do

```
function saveUser(user) {
    return user.saveAsync();
}
```

Comment: True... but that would only work for user. Be better to have a better promise for all saves